# if statements acting differently

Tags: java, list, if-statement, while-loop

Doing a homework problem with the following code, when I enter -1 when the program runs, controller inserts the String even though it's not supposed to when -1 is entered. The do while loop uses the same code for the while statement and it exits correctly, im not sure why the other code doesn't work the way I think it should.  I'm very new to Java and programming, any help is appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Control controller;
    String userInput = "";
    //InputStream fs1;
    BufferedReader br1;
   // int count = 0;
    controller = new Control(userInput);
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Please input a String and press Enter.");
        System.out.println("Inputting -1 will terminate the building "
                + "and input process.");
        br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        if(!"-1".equals(userInput))
        {
            userInput = br1.readLine();
            controller.insert(userInput);
        }
    System.out.print("\n"+ "User input: "+ userInput + "\n\n");

    }// end do
    while (!"-1".equals(userInput));

    System.out.println("\nList initialized based on your inputs:\n");  
    controller.display();

}
```

here's what I ran:
run:
Please input a String and press Enter.
Inputting -1 will terminate the building and input process.
5

User input: 5

Please input a String and press Enter.
Inputting -1 will terminate the building and input process.
4

User input: 4

Please input a String and press Enter.
Inputting -1 will terminate the building and input process.
3

User input: 3

Please input a String and press Enter.
Inputting -1 will terminate the building and input process.
-1

User input: -1

List initialized based on your inputs:

List (first-->last): -1 3 4 5 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

-1 should not be in the List. Any advice?

Comment: Don't keep creating a new BufferedReader inside of the loop. Create it once *before* the loop.

Comment: In addition, your condition is bad form; it took me a few milliseconds too long to parse it.  Use `while(!userInput.Equals("-1"))`

Comment: @RobertHarvey: the OP's way is actually a pretty common idiom which neatly handles the case where `userInput` is null. It ensures an NPE cannot occur; and since the general contract for `equals` specifies false should be returned when called with a null argument, it ensures end of input (when `readLine` returns null) is handled correctly.

Comment: @Mac: Ick.  But OK.  This is much cleaner in C#

Answer (score 4):

you have your test in the wrong place. You are reading data and putting it into the list without testing it.

```
    if(!"-1".equals(userInput))
    {
        userInput = br1.readLine();
        controller.insert(userInput);
    }
```

should be

```
    userInput = br1.readLine();
    if(!"-1".equals(userInput))
    {
        controller.insert(userInput);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that you are checking after the insert:

```
   if(!"-1".equals(userInput))
    {
        userInput = br1.readLine();
        controller.insert(userInput);
    }
```

This could be one fix:

```
   userInput = br1.readLine();
   if(!"-1".equals(userInput))
    {
        controller.insert(userInput);
    }
```